# Replacing repeating fields in a .ini file

Tags: text-processing

Hi im new to this so please bear with me on this. I have a config file .ini that I'm trying to edit via cl and I'm trying to write a script where I can simply replace their set values. e.g changing false to true

```
[logs] 
enabled = false 

[smtp] 
enabled = false 

[system] 
enabled = false
```

How can I set enable to true for smtp using sed or awk ( or any other tool ) and save the file without writing the output to the shell itself

Edit: I tried using this `sed -i 's/[smtp]\nenabled = false/[smtp]\nenabled = true/' file.ini` but it does not work for me

Comment: you have your answer already in your tag: `sed` is the tool you need, and this is a simple problem that a lot of websites have examples for!

Comment: @MarcusMüller can you share one of the websites that deals with new line? I've tried using this script 'sed -i 's/[smtp]\nenabled = false/[smtp]\nenabled = true/'' but it does not work and from what I know sed is a line editor which cant read multiple inputs on multiple lines but can output it

Comment: [crudini](https://github.com/pixelb/crudini) may be your solution. It is available at least in Ubuntu.

Comment: Don't just say `it does not work for me` as that tells us nothing about the problem, tell us in what way it doesn't work - wrong output, no output, error messages, core dumps, etc. Also add the expected output - showing sample input is only half the example and if you have more or less than a single line saying `enabled = false` in each block then show that as otherwise we don't have a realistic example to test a potential solution with.

Comment: While sed can be made to read and operate on multiple lines, doing so is a pain, usually involving non-portable constructs, and is just not worth it when an awk solution will be some combination of clearer, simpler, more efficient, more robust, more portable, and easier to enhance/maintain in future. If you're drawn to GNU sed for `-i` then use GNU awk for `-i inplace` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your INI-file is actually a well-formed TOML-file.  [TOML](https://toml.io/en/) (Tom's Obvious, Minimal Language) is a structured document format used for configuration files.  Being a structured document format, line-oriented tools like `sed` aren't really suited to parse it, partly because data may be multi-line (TOML supports "arrays of tables") and partly because data may be encoded.

Using a TOML-aware tool not only provides you with a safe way to access and modify your file, it also makes doing this very easy.

Using `tomlq`, a TOML parser wrapper around the `jq` JSON parser, which is part of `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

```bsh
tomlq -t '.smtp.enabled |= true' file.ini
```

This reads your TOML-file and updates the `smtp` section's `enabled` key with a new value.

The output, given the data in your question, would be

```
[logs]
enabled = false

[smtp]
enabled = true

[system]
enabled = false
```

The `tomlq` tool may also make changes "in-place" using its `-i` or `--in-place` option.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '/]/{tag=$1} (tag=="[smtp]") && ($1=="enabled"){$3="true"} 1' file
[logs]
enabled = false

[smtp]
enabled = true

[system]
enabled = false
```

or maybe:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"} $1=="[smtp]"{$2="enabled = true"} 1' file
[logs]
enabled = false

[smtp]
enabled = true

[system]
enabled = false
```

or various other things... The right answer really all depends what else your input file contains other than what you've shown in your example so far.

Answer (score -1):

command:

```
sed -i '/smtp/{n;s/false/true/g}' file
```

output

```
[logs]
enabled = false

[smtp]
enabled = true

[system]
enabled = false
```